# How can I display the category id as well as the name on the category tree in the admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to be able to prepend category id to category name in the category tree of the admin panel so that all category ids are visible without having to go into each category.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you want to show all category and child category tree ?

Comment: I want to show the category id next to the category name when the tree is rendered in the admin panel.

eg:
- id 701: Televisions (37)
-- id 702: 31" screen (10)